# On $S$-semipermutable Hall subgroups, such that $H^G$ is solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Two subgroup $A, B \le G$ are said to *permute* if $AB = BA$. A subgroup $H \le G$ is called $S$-semipermutable in $G$ if $H$ permutes with every *Sylow* $q$-subgroup of $G$ for primes $q$ not dividing $|H|$.

**Theorem:** Let $H$ be an $S$-semipermutable $\pi$-subgroup of $G$. Then $H^G$ contains a nilpotent $\pi$-complement, and all $\pi$-complements in $H^G$ are conjugate. Also, if $\pi$ consists of a single prime, then $H^G$ is solvable.

In the proof of the following corollary I do not understand why we need to suppose that $H$ is a Hall subgroup, further I think $\pi$-complement to a group $H$ means an complement such that  this complement is a $\pi$-group? (I nowhere found a definition, but I guess it means this). So now to the corollary:

**Corollary:** Suppose that $H$ is a nilpotent Hall subgroup of $G$ and that $H$ is $S$-semipermutable. Then $H^G$ is solvable.

*Proof*: Let $\pi$ be the set of prime divisors of $|H|$. Then $H^G$ has a nilpotent $\pi$-complement $K$, and thus $H^G = HK$. Since both $H$ and $K$ are nilpotent, the solvability of $H^G$ follows by the Wieland-Kegel Theorem. $\square$

Comment: A group $K$ (like $K=H^G$) is said to have a $\pi$-complement if it has a subgroup $C$ whose order is not divisible by any prime in $\pi$ but whose index $[K:C]$ is divisible only by primes in $\pi$. A nilpotent $\pi$-complement means that additionally $C$ is a nilpotent group. The most typical usage is when $\pi$ consists of a single prime, in which case a $p$-complement is a subgroup $C$ such that $CP=G$ and $C \cap P=1$ for some Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$. Such a $C$ is automatically nilpotent.

Comment: You said a group $K$ is said to have a $\pi$-complement if it has a subgroup $C \le K$... but in your last sentence you wrote $C \cap P = 1$, so obviously $C$ is not a subgroup of $P$, or do you mean a $\pi$-complement of $K$ in $G$ is a subgroup $C$ of $G$ whose order is not divisible by any prime in $\pi$ but whose index $[G : C]$ is divisible only by primes in $\pi$?

Comment: In my comment, change one "G" to "K", and strike the last sentence which was crazy: The most typical usage is when $\pi$ consists of a single prime $p$, in which case a $p$-complement of $K$ is a subgroup $C\leq K$ such that $CP=K$ and $C\cap P=1$ for some Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $K$. Such a subgroup $C$ is **not** automatically nilpotent.

Comment: Such a $C$ is a complement **to** $P$, hence is a $p$-complement **of** $K$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But why in the proof follows that $K$ is a complement **to** $H$ in $H^G$? Why it could not be a complement to some other group in $H^G$?

Comment: Because $H$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $H^G$ and $K$ is a Hall $\pi'$-subgroup of $H^G$ and $HK=KH$.